# Gibberish Text in Some Part of the Software in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, characters

Don't know which actions and / or system update causing the problem, I found some gibberish text in some parts causing failure of the software (e.g.: Weird characters in rclone caused transfer failure, similar weird text input in obs input field)

OBS weird text shown in input

[obs weird characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hapX.jpg)

rclone task window also shown failure caused by weird character

[rclone weird characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIky2.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Resolved... although I don't know which action actually did the job... I removed the following recently installed packages. Python 3.4, Python Launcher, A chinese input software, a color picker software, android backup software - Helium. And I also configure the following language and region settings as shown in https://www.digitalcitizen.life/changing-display-language-used-non-unicode-programs, changing the "Language for non-Unicode programs" from Chinese (Taiwan) to English

Comment: If you have an answer, you should submit an answer, instead of a comment.